# Vanilla JavaScript: delete spans after animation ends

Tags: javascript, animation

I use anime.js to animate headings. It adds spans to all letters to animate them individually. After the animation I like to delete this spans from the text, but deletion doesn't working. This is the code:

```
function theAnimation() {
  var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.pt-animation');
  textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

  anime.timeline({
    loop: false,
    delay: 500
  })
  .add({
    targets: '.pt-animation .letter',
    translateX: [40,0],
    translateZ: 0,
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 1200,
    delay: (el, i) => 500 + 30 * i
  })
}

function deleteSpan(){
  var letter = document.getElementsByClassName("letter");
  delete letter;
}

theAnimation();
deleteSpan();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**`complete()`**](https://animejs.com/documentation/#beginComplete) callback is triggered once when the animation is completed.

To delete element from `DOM`, Use [`elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

```js
function theAnimation() {
  var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.pt-animation');
  textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

  anime.timeline({
      loop: false,
      delay: 500
    })
    .add({
      targets: '.pt-animation .letter',
      translateX: [40, 0],
      translateZ: 0,
      opacity: [0, 1],
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 1200,
      delay: (el, i) => 500 + 30 * i,
      complete: deleteSpan
    });
}

function deleteSpan() {
  var letter = document.getElementsByClassName("letter");
  for (var i = 0, len = letter.length; i < len; i++) {
    letter[i].parentNode.removeChild(letter[i]);
  }
}

theAnimation();
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort Rayon! I tried your cose, it works only halfway: it removes compeltly some of the letters from the heading. I like the letters to be stay as is after the animation, only want the <span> tags remove from around them.

Comment: @Nadam - I wrote code as per your selector. Could you provide some identity so that I will use a specific selector? I assume `document.querySelectorAll("span.letter");` should work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove method:

```
var letter = document.getElementsByClassName("letter")[0];
letter.remove();
```